# ASP SQL Server query error on a time field

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I have some asp pages that lets users enter details into a database with several tables. Part of the ASP pages lets users query the database based on Project Numbers.

All the data entry works ok, but I am getting errors when trying to display a query. The error only happens on the Time fields I have in the database tables. Any table with a time field brings back an error.

Hopefully someone can help me get past this.

I have 6 Recordsets set up for the different tables, and 3 of these have time fields.
An example of one of the recordsets with a time field that I want to display in a table would be:

```
<td><%=(Recordset6.Fields.Item("StartTime").Value)%></td>
```

When I run a query the code stops and highlights the line above, and I also get the error message:

> Response object: 007~ASP 0101~Unexpected error~The function returned
>   |.

As I said I have several tables, and there are around 5 references to times in these tables.
All other data returns as I expected, but if the time fields are included I get the above error on each of the 5 time fields.

If I remove the references to the time fields the data displays correctly.

I am using SQL Server 2012, and the time columsn are defined as `Time(0)` data types.

The data in the tables seems ok, and If I run a query in Management studio I get the records returned and the time field above displays 11:25:00

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked with ASP for a long long time, maybe ASP does not know how to handle `Time` data type. Why don't you convert the `Time` datatype to `VARCHAR` while fetching the data?

```
SELECT convert(varchar(50), @t) AS Time, data1, data2, .... from yourtable
```

Comment: You are correct about ASP not handling the time field correctly. Once I converted the field the data came through ok. Thanks for the help